# How do I print a deck of cards side by side?

Tags: java

Working on a Crazy Eights game for my high school project. I'm trying to print the some of the cards to the console side by side. But I'm having trouble doing that.

Here's what I got:

Game.java:

```
public class game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.shuffle();
    }
}
```

Deck.java:

```
class Deck extends ArrayList<Card> {
    private String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    private String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "1"};

    public Deck() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++) {
                this.add(new Card(Integer.parseInt(ranks[i]), suits[j]));
            }
        }
    }

    void shuffle() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 52 - 1; i++) {
            int randomValue = i + random.nextInt(52 - i);
            Card card = this.get(i);
            this.set(i, this.get(randomValue));
            this.set(randomValue, card);
        }
        Card card = this.get(0);
        System.out.println(card.face(card.getValue(), card.getSuit()));
        card = this.get(1);
        System.out.println(card.face(card.getValue(), card.getSuit()));
    }
}
```

Card.java:

```
class Card {
    private int value = 0;
    private String suit = null;
    private String face = "";
    private String back = "";

    public Card(int value, String suit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    String face(int value, String suit) {
        face += ("+-----------+" + "\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if(j == 0 && i != 3) {
                    face += ("|  " + " ");
                } else if(j == 1 && i == 1) {
                    if(value >= 10) {
                        face += (" " + value + " ");
                    } else {
                        face += ("  " + value + " ");
                    }
                } else if (i != 3) {
                    face += ("   " + " ");
                }

                if (j == 0 && i == 3) {
                    if(suit.equals("Clubs")) {
                        face += ("|   CLUBS   ");
                    } else if(suit.equals("Diamonds")) {
                        face += ("| DIAMONDS  ");
                    } else if(suit.equals("Hearts")) {
                        face += ("|   HEARTS  ");
                    } else if(suit.equals("Spades")) {
                        face += ("|   SPADES  ");
                    }
                }
            }
            face += ("|");
            face += ("\n");
        }
        face += ("+-----------+"  + "\n");
        return face;
    }
}
```

There's obviously more code that I have written for this project, but it's not relevant to the question I'm asking. I think I've shown enough for my question. So basically what happens is when I print the cards using the `void shuffle()` function, it prints like this:

```
+-----------+
|           |
|    10     |
|           |
|   SPADES  |
|           |
|           |
+-----------+

+-----------+
|           |
|    11     |
|           |
|   HEARTS  |
|           |
|           |
+-----------+
```

How do I make the console print the cards side by side?

Oh yeah, before anyone asks why I extended ArrayList in class `Deck`, it's requirement that my high school teacher made me follow and I don't even understand why.

Comment: In general it's hard to manipulate console output in that way, because once you write to the console you can't go back and change it. You'll have to build `String`s that contain a "horizontal slice" of each card, and then print out all of those `String`s at the end.

Comment: try to work out (on paper) what your logic would be.  Probably you will realize that most of output would be command and all you got to change  is the print of the number and the suit.  So maybe start with printing x amount of blank cards?

Comment: This is likely more difficult than you think. You'll need to remove the newlines off of right of each card, then concatenate each line of each card together. You'll also need to do it *before* you print. I've never heard of manipulating text that's already been output to the console, and anything doing that would would likely be easier achieved by pre-processing the string.

Comment: And you guys all seem to have one bad teacher that insists on extending ArrayList; there's been multiple such questions. At least you know it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

have face return an array of strings (one for each row).

then print the first row of each card and a line break, then the second row, etc.

Comment: Or, in OP's case of cards side-by-side: first row of card #1, some space, first row of card #2, a line break; then second row of card #1, some space, second row of card #2, a line break, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need some changes in your code. 
**First:** face should return list of String where list contains string of row by row.
**Second:** In shuffle where you want to print cards you print row of first card, give some space and row of 2nd card and line break for each row.

```
    List<String> face(int value, String suit) {
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("+-----------+");
//        face += ("+-----------+" + "\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            String str="";
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if(j == 0 && i != 3) {
                    str += ("|  " + " ");
                } else if(j == 1 && i == 1) {
                    if(value >= 10) {
                        str += (" " + value + " ");
                    } else {
                        str += ("  " + value + " ");
                    }
                } else if (i != 3) {
                    str += ("   " + " ");
                }

                if (j == 0 && i == 3) {
                    if(suit.equals("Clubs")) {
                        str += ("|   CLUBS   ");
                    } else if(suit.equals("Diamonds")) {
//                        list.add("| DIAMONDS  ");
                        str += ("| DIAMONDS  ");
                    } else if(suit.equals("Hearts")) {
//                        list.add("|   HEARTS  ");
                        str += ("|   HEARTS  ");
                    } else if(suit.equals("Spades")) {
//                        list.add("|   SPADES  ");
                        str += ("|   SPADES  ");
                    }
                }
            }


            str += ("|");
            list.add(str);
//            face += ("\n");
        }
        list.add("+-----------+");
//        face += ("+-----------+"  + "\n");
        return list;
    }
```

In shuffle,

```
Card card = this.get(0);
        List<String> card0=card.face(card.getValue(), card.getSuit());
        card = this.get(1);
        List<String> card1=card.face(card.getValue(), card.getSuit());

        for(int i=0;i<card0.size();i++){
            System.out.print(card0.get(i)+"  ");
            System.out.println(card1.get(i));
        }
```